# Shiny with ggplot and dashboardPage doesn't work

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I don't understand why this app doesn't work?
The app works without the content within the server part.
It works whith the UI definition and the server function empty.
When I added ggplot code   in server function the app leaf to work.
Could you help me?

Thanks

```
#install.packages("quantmod")
#install.packages('circlepackeR')
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)

apple=as.data.frame(getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = "2010-01-01", to = "2020-10-15", auto.assign = FALSE))
colnames(apple)=c('Apertura','Maximo','Minimo','Cierre','Volumen','Ajustado')
apple$fecha=as.Date(rownames(apple))


ui <- fluidPage(
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "SP500 Top-5"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Apple", tabName = "aapl")
    )
  ),
dashboardBody(
  # tags$head(
  #   tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
  # ),
  tabItems(
    
  tabItem(tabName = "aapl",
            fluidRow(
              tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plota1")), 
                tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")), 
                tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))

            )))))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  apple=reactive({apple})
  
  output$plota1 <- renderPlot({
    g=ggplot()+
      geom_line(mapping=aes(x=fecha, y=Cierre), data=apple(), size=1, alpha=0.5)+
      scale_x_date("Fecha") +  scale_y_continuous(name="Serie de precios de cierre")+ 
      ggtitle ("Comportamiento diario de la acción APPPLE") 
    g
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the server, change the reactive name to something other than `apple`.  I defined it as `df1`, and used `airquality` data, and I get the output as shown below.  Otherwise, your code is fine.

```
apple <- as.data.frame(airquality)
apple$fecha <- apple$Day
apple$Cierre <- apple$Temp


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "SP500 Top-5"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Apple", tabName = "aapl")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      # tags$head(
      #   tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
      # ),
      tabItems(
        
        tabItem(tabName = "aapl",
                fluidRow(
                  tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plota1")), 
                    tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")), 
                    tabPanel("Table", DTOutput("table"))
                    
                  ))))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
   
  df1 <- reactive({apple})
  
  output$plota1 <- renderPlot({
    g <- ggplot(data=df1())+
      geom_line(mapping=aes(x=fecha, y=Cierre), size=1, alpha=0.5)+
      #scale_x_date("Fecha") +  scale_y_continuous(name="Serie de precios de cierre")+
      ggtitle ("Comportamiento diario de la acción APPPLE")
    g
  })
  output$table <- renderDT(df1())
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge on all things R is still a bit low especially when it comes to shiny. But to try get better I've been involving myself in the Qs to see if I can find a work through.

With this one, in the server code I removed

```
apple=reactive({apple})
```

and `data=apple()`. Knowing ggplot I wasn't sure why apple was a function anyway so I just had it read `data=apple`

This got the server ui function to run graph as shown. Obviously you haven't included any information on the summary or table parts so they remain blank. This worked for me, but I could be completely way off the mark and could run into other problems down the line.

Comment: In `shiny` you define `reactive`s like `apple=reactive({apple})`. They are basically functions, and to get the value you need to evaluate it with the brackets: `apple()`

Comment: Ah perfect, didn't even ask the Q and I'm still learning something!